# Where are the Winter Bash and hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2023

This 2023-2024 winter, there weren't any hats.

What happened?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392846/248731

Comment: Fun has been deprioritised.

Comment: [The beatings will continue until morale improves](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/371325).

Comment: [We hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Comment: Let's stop calling it fun. It wasn't fun, it was a tradition. Traditions come and go, an actual fun one in my opinion would be to change your avatar. Edit the hat in yourself, scuffed or not scuffed. A little personal effort rather than the company having to do the work.

Answer (score 18):

Back in September of this year (2023-09-06) staff posted [an announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392846/1099857) indicating that they would no longer be doing Winter/Summer Bash event. This announcement was featured for ~3 weeks from post date until [2023-09-27](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/392846/2).

Here is some of their rationale:

> After last year’s event, we analyzed some of the data, and this is what we found:
>
> - Only 1% of community members who came to the site during Winter Bash chose to wear a hat during the event.
> - The total contributions from people who were participating in Winter Bash were lower than those who weren’t participating. This means people would come, participate enough to earn a hat, and then drop off again.
> - We do know that a number of community members enjoy participating in Winter Bash, but each year we receive more feedback on how the concept has grown a bit stale.

With a final conclusion to sunset being:

> In addition to the data and feedback shared above, we also looked at how expensive it is to run Winter Bash every year. From the outside, it may seem like a simple event, but it’s actually quite complex. For last year’s Winter Bash, three engineers spent two months building, launching, maintaining, and ending the event. There were also four community managers who were heavily involved, a Product Manager, and resources from our Design, Marketing, and other teams.
>
> In the end, the lift and time required for Winter Bash is too great for the team to take on. This year we have an even smaller number of staff members on Product, Engineering, and Community, and we had to make the call that we don’t have the bandwidth to run this event.

Comment: The engineering weight of the event is indeed surprising. What about making the winter bash project open source, and let the community maintain it ? I have the feeling the code can be reused, and the engineering/product cost every year reduced significantly.